# Converting binary representation of integers to ASCII in Java Card

Tags: java, binary, integer, javacard

I would like to convert arbitrary length of integers that are represented in binary format to the ASCII form.

One example being for the integer number `33023`, the hexadecimal bytes is `0x80ff`. I would like to represent `0x80ff` into ASCII format of `33023` which has a hexadecimal representation of `0x3333303233`.

I am working on a **Java Card** environment which does not recognize the String type so I would have to do the conversion manually via binary manipulation.

What is the most efficient way to go about solving this as Java Card environment on a 16 bit smart card is very constraint.

Comment: If you don't have `String`, do you at least have `char` arrays and/or `byte` arrays?

Comment: There is only byte, byte[], int, int[], short, short[] types as the basic primitives.

Comment: Excellent! A `short[]` is a good substitute for a `String` in a pinch; even a `byte[]` would do for ASCII.  So as long as we also have both `/` (divide) and `%` (remainder) operators on `short`s (or `byte`s), we're golden (;->)

Comment: Yes you can do both / and % on short.

Comment: `int` and `int[]` are generally not supported on Java Card platforms. When specifying the number format you're only showing an example: `0x80FF`. This probably is an unsigned, big endian format consisting of two bytes, `0x80` and `0xFF`. You're specifying the output format fully, please also remind yourself to indicate the input format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more tricky than that you may think as it requires base conversion, and base conversion is executed over the entire number, using big integer arithmetic.

That of course doesn't mean that we cannot create an efficient implementation of said big integer arithmetic specifically for the purpose. Here is an implementation that left pads with zero's (which is usually required on Java Card) and uses no additional memory (!). You may have to copy the original value of the big endian number if you want to keep it though - the input value is overwritten. Putting it in RAM is highly recommended.

This code simply divides the bytes with the new base (10 for decimals), returning the remainder. The remainder is the next *lowest* digit. As the input value has now been divided the next remainder is the digit that is just one position more significant than the one before. It keeps dividing and returning the remainder until the value is zero and the calculation is complete.

The tricky part of the algorithm is the inner loop, which divides the value by 10 in place, while returning the remainder using tail division over bytes. It provides one remainder / decimal digit per run. This also means that the order of the function is *O(n)* where *n* is the number of digits in the result (defining the tail division as a single operation). Note that *n* can be calculated by `ceil(bigNumBytes * log_10(256))`: the result of which is also present in the precalculated `BCD_SIZE_PER_BYTES` table. `log_10(256)` of course a constant decimal value, somewhere upwards of `2.408`.

Here is the final code with optimizations (see the edit for different versions):

```
/**
 * Converts an unsigned big endian value within the buffer to the same value
 * stored using ASCII digits. The ASCII digits may be zero padded, depending
 * on the value within the buffer.
 * <p>
 * <strong>Warning:</strong> this method zeros the value in the buffer that
 * contains the original number. It is strongly recommended that the input
 * value is in fast transient memory as it will be overwritten multiple
 * times - until it is all zero.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * <strong>Warning:</strong> this method fails if not enough bytes are
 * available in the output BCD buffer while destroying the input buffer.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * <strong>Warning:</strong> the big endian number can only occupy 16 bytes
 * or less for this implementation.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param uBigBuf
 *            the buffer containing the unsigned big endian number
 * @param uBigOff
 *            the offset of the unsigned big endian number in the buffer
 * @param uBigLen
 *            the length of the unsigned big endian number in the buffer
 * @param decBuf
 *            the buffer that is to receive the BCD encoded number
 * @param decOff
 *            the offset in the buffer to receive the BCD encoded number
 * @return decLen, the length in the buffer of the received BCD encoded
 *         number
 */
public static short toDecimalASCII(byte[] uBigBuf, short uBigOff,
        short uBigLen, byte[] decBuf, short decOff) {

    // variables required to perform long division by 10 over bytes
    // possible optimization: reuse remainder for dividend (yuk!)
    short dividend, division, remainder;

    // calculate stuff outside of loop
    final short uBigEnd = (short) (uBigOff + uBigLen);
    final short decDigits = BYTES_TO_DECIMAL_SIZE[uBigLen];

    // --- basically perform division by 10 in a loop, storing the remainder

    // traverse from right (least significant) to the left for the decimals
    for (short decIndex = (short) (decOff + decDigits - 1); decIndex >= decOff; decIndex--) {

        // --- the following code performs tail division by 10 over bytes

        // clear remainder at the start of the division
        remainder = 0;

        // traverse from left (most significant) to the right for the input
        for (short uBigIndex = uBigOff; uBigIndex < uBigEnd; uBigIndex++) {

            // get rest of previous result times 256 (bytes are base 256)
            // ... and add next positive byte value
            // optimization: doing shift by 8 positions instead of mul.
            dividend = (short) ((remainder << 8) + (uBigBuf[uBigIndex] & 0xFF));

            // do the division
            division = (short) (dividend / 10);

            // optimization: perform the modular calculation using
            // ... subtraction and multiplication
            // ... instead of calculating the remainder directly
            remainder = (short) (dividend - division * 10);

            // store the result in place for the next iteration
            uBigBuf[uBigIndex] = (byte) division;
        }
        // the remainder is what we were after
        // add '0' value to create ASCII digits
        decBuf[decIndex] = (byte) (remainder + '0');
    }

    return decDigits;
}

/*
 * pre-calculated array storing the number of decimal digits for big endian
 * encoded number with len bytes: ceil(len * log_10(256))
 */
private static final byte[] BYTES_TO_DECIMAL_SIZE = { 0, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13,
        15, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 29, 32, 34, 37, 39 };
```

To extend the input size simply calculate and store the next decimal sizes in the table...

Comment: It works in an actual Java Card :) . Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Added an optimized version with comments. Removed intermediate version... Again: please test on JC!